# pip install ourSQL "Cannot find the file specified"

Tags: python, pip, oursql

When I try to use pip to install oursql I run into the following error

```
 C:\Users\user>pip install oursql
    Collecting oursql
      Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/8c/88/9f53a314a2af6f56c0a1249c5673ee384b85dc791bac5c1228772ced3502/oursql-0.9.3.2.tar.gz
    Installing collected packages: oursql
      Running setup.py install for oursql ... error
        Complete output from command c:\python27\python.exe -u -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='c:\\users\\user\\appdata\\local\\temp\\pip-install-l7rkx0\\oursql\\setup.py';f=getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('\r\n', '\n');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, 'exec'))" install --record c:\users\user\appdata\local\temp\pip-record-yke4zh\install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile:
        cython not found, using previously-cython'd .c file.
        running install
        running build
        running build_ext
        error: [Error 2] The system cannot find the file specified

        ----------------------------------------
    Command "c:\python27\python.exe -u -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='c:\\users\\user\\appdata\\local\\temp\\pip-install-l7rkx0\\oursql\\setup.py';f=getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('\r\n', '\n');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, 'exec'))" install --record c:\users\user\appdata\local\temp\pip-record-yke4zh\install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile" failed with error code 1 in c:\users\user\appdata\local\temp\pip-install-l7rkx0\oursql\
```

And I run into the same error when I try to install from source

```
C:\Users\user\Downloads\oursql-0.9.3.1>python setup.py install
cython not found, using previously-cython'd .c file.
running install
running build
running build_ext
error: [Error 2] The system cannot find the file specified
```

I've tried running cmd as administrator and the same errors occurred. Any help in this would be appreciated.

(Windows 10, Python 2.7)

Comment: try installing cython: `pip install cython oursql`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

https://github.com/python-oursql/oursql/issues/18

You need [Cython](http://cython.org/) to compile `oursql` because the author has forgotten to commit generated modules.

As the author of oursql seems to disappear I [forked the module](https://github.com/sqlobject/oursql), committed missed generated files and applied [pull requests](https://github.com/python-oursql/oursql/pulls). I doubt I will develop it further but I can accept pull requests.